# What happens if I take the double derivative of EMF with respect to angular displacement

Tags: electromagnetism

I knew that I would get an Sinusoidal curve in the first derivative but what happens in the second derivative. Is there any specific quantity for this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? What system are you considering i.e. what EMF are you measuring? An AC voltage applied across some component in an electrical circuit? An electromagnetic wave?

Comment: Hi John
I am considering the case of a dynamo it is an AC voltage circuit...